# Is it possible to expand only certain columns in an oversized table using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a flexible-width table whose cells can be populated with arbitrary content.  However, I would like to be able to dictate that certain columns should not expand past their natural non-breaking width using only CSS.  It seems like this should be possible by having the columns take a mixture of widths 'auto' and percentages:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <col style="width: auto" />
  <col style="width: 100%" />
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sender Name</td>
      <td>Subject Line</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, this does not seem to work.  Is there a way to do this using CSS only?  I cannot use `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: Would you benefit at all from `max-width`/`min-width`?

Comment: Mhhh I don't understand well the problem, but maybe you can use min-width and max-width in some way?

Comment: I don't think so, because I don't know what the natural non-breaking width of a table column is.

Comment: To be clear, when that table is rendered in a container larger than necessary to fit all of the table cells' contents without breaking, I want the "Sender Name" column to keep its natural non-breaking width and the "Subject Line" column to expand to the remaining width

Answer (score 4):

Without some actual width definitions you have to apply nowrap. The good news is you can apply this to the one cell and go. It shouldn't break any of your other code. Look here:

http://jsbin.com/axuhum/5

Also if you do not set the table to be 100%, but rather the cell you want to auto-expand then it will.  :)

Here's the code for reference.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Sender Name</td>
      <td style="width: 100%;">Subject Line</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```